# Sanitizing dates using sed or awk on an ldapsearch query

Tags: ldap, sed, date, awk, ldif

I'd like to pipe the output of an ldapsearch to sanitize the dates returned - I presume sed and/or awk can help with this but would appreciate a bit of help.

The fixed length date format in the LDIF output file is like this:

```
whenCreated: 20111209103130.0Z
```

Any pointers to get it in this format would be great:

```
whenCreated: DD-MM-YY hh:mm
```

eg (using above example):

```
whenCreated: 09-12-2011 10:31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this little piece of `sed` help you?

```
sed -e 's/whenCreated: \([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\).*/whenCreated: \3-\2-\1 \4:\5/g'
```